# SELECT Distinct FROM two tables . MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, distinct

I have 2 different tables that each have a column called id_product. How can I get the DISTINCT values of id_field across both tables?

```
tb_compare
-id_product

tb_product_field 
-id_product
-id_field


 $qasql1 = mysql_query("SELECT c1.*,
           c2.DISTINCT(id_field) FROM  tb_compare AS c1 
           INNER JOIN tb_product_field AS c2 ON c1.id_product=c2.id_product 
           WHERE c1.compareSession = '$sessionID'  ORDER BY c1.compareID Desc "
          );
```

Thanks!!

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, i try to put GROUP BY  instead to ORDER BY,and i remove DINSTINCT.

```
$qasql1 = mysql_query("SELECT c1.*,
       c2.id_field FROM  tb_compare AS c1 
       INNER JOIN tb_product_field AS c2 ON c1.id_product=c2.id_product 
       WHERE c1.compareSession = '$sessionID' GROUP BY c1.compareID Desc "
      );
```

thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `union`:

```
select id_product
from tb_compare
union
select id_product
from tb_product_field;
```

Note that `union` removes duplicate rows in a list, so `distinct` is not necessary.  In this case, a row consists only of a single value.

Comment: @AlexW . . . The "row" in question consists of one column, `id_product` (from one table or the other).  So, it makes the row distinct which has the effect of returning the distinct values for that column.  Perhaps you are confusing this with having a `*` in the `select` list.

Comment: I was just getting stuck on the language where you said duplicate values instead of duplicate rows. At first, I didn't realize you had selected only a single column. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN both of the tables first, and then do a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_field FROM
    (SELECT * FROM tb_compare AS c1 
        INNER JOIN tb_product_field AS c2 
        ON c1.id_product=c2.id_product 
        WHERE c1.compareSession = '$sessionID' 
        ORDER BY c1.compareID Desc
     )
```

Comment: Can you answer my question if you have a time please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035464/people-are-shown-twice-on-the-chat-page-because-of-query